# DLookup not refreshing - VBA to open file path

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm pulling my hair out on this one.

I put together some code for opening a file associated with records in our database.  Newer data has full file paths stored as text in a separate table.  Old data does not have a full file path but has enough details to assemble a working path in most cases.

My code checks to see if the older data fields are null and if they are proceed to the newer filepath.

The problem I'm having is with DLookup in the IF statement being stuck on the first file it was used on.  No matter what I do, DLookup always returns the same result as the first time I ran the code.  I'm stumped.

```
Private Sub btnOpenFile_Click()
Dim FacID As String
Dim FacIDShort As String
Dim CDID As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileURL As String

FacID = [FAC_ID]
FacIDShort = Left(FacID, 4)

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
If IsNull([CD_NUM]) Then ' Checks to see if old file path exists before trying new file path
  FileURL = DLookup("[File_Path]", "tblFileDirectory", "[Drawing_ID]")
  Application.FollowHyperlink (FileURL)
Else
  CDID = [CD_NUM]
  FileName = [FILENAME]
  FileURL = ("\\SYSTEMXXX\" & FacIDShort & "\" & FacID & "\FILES\" & CDID & "\" & FileName)
  Application.FollowHyperlink (FileURL)
End If
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  LogError (FileURL)
  MsgBox ("Error: " & FileURL & vbNewLine & "The URL Does Not Exist.")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DLookup("[File_Path]", "tblFileDirectory", "[Drawing_ID]" should actually be more like DLookup("[File_Path]", "tblFileDirectory", "MyDrawingIdColumnInTable = MyDrawingIdToLookFor"